# Connect to EC2 and create a new instance if a volume attached to the instance goes down

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-ec2

Our mongodb database is in AWS. The database is attached as a volume to the EC2 instance. Now I need to implement like: If the EC2 instance goes down I need to detach the volume, create a new instance and then connect that volume to the new instance.

Am stuck with how to get status of my EC2 box, so that if it is down I need to detach the volume and create a new EC2 and attach the instance.

```
import boto
import boto.ec2
ec2Conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region name and required parameters)
reservations= ec2Conn.get_all_instances();
```

Comment: Have you seen [EC2 Instance Recovery](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html)?  It is designed to automatically rebuild a failed instance.

Comment: What situation are you trying to "survive"? What do you mean by "If the eC2 instance goes down" -- are you referring to an EC2 infrastructure issue, or an app issue? If there is a problem in one Availability Zone, then your method won't help because the volume is in the failed AZ (not that it happens, but just in case). Have you experienced a problem you're trying to avoid again?

Comment: thanks Micheal, EC2 instance Recovery works for my kind of scenario